# Providing specific implementation of generic Java type at runtime via Spring

Tags: java, spring, testng

I am facing the following issue combining Java generics and Spring. It essentially involves requiring an abstraction of a number of components that will be determined at run time. I have a class that contains an autowired field that is an interface which is implemented by a class that takes a generic type which is then subsequently used by a sequence of callers. It needs to be instantiated at runtime with a specific implementation of that generic type. This is the scenario.

```
public interface A {
    void setValues(Object obj);
}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class SuperType {
// some fields and methods
}

public interface ObjType<T extends SuperType> {
    void method(T values);
}

@Component
public class B<T extends SuperType> implements A {
    // field objType that requires T 
    @Autowired
    private ObjType<T> objType;


    public void setValues(Object obj) {
        // sets values of T through a method that can be overridden
        T values = getValues(obj);

        // calls objType's method
        objType.method(values);
    }

    protected T getValues(Object obj) {
        // some values being set here for supertype and being cast to T
        SuperType s = new SuperType();
        return (T) s;
}
```

Now the more specific implementations -

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class SubType extends SuperType {
     // sub type specific fields and methods
}

@Component
public class SomeObj implements ObjType<SubType> {
    public void method(SubType values) {
         // some implementation
    }
}
```

How it is actually being called and instantiated

```
@Component
public class ConfigInfo {
    // some fields
    @Autowired
    private A a;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        a.setValues(this);
    }
}

@Test
public class TestClass extends SomeSpringTestBase {
    @Autowired
    private ConfigInfo info;
}
```

I have tried providing the more specific implementation through the Spring context configuration, and including this configuration on the test base

```
@Configuration
public class SpringTestConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public B<SubType> getA() {
        B<SubType> b = new B<SubType>();
        return b;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public SomeObj getObjType() {
        SomeObj obj = new SomeObj();
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Essentially, I need the implementation `B<SubType>` to be used at run time for an instance of `A`, and `SomeObj` to be used for an instance of `ObjType<T>`, but this needs to be injected by Sprong. At this point, I am not sure if I am using the generics part or the Spring part or both incorrectly. This is the error I am getting.

> [testng] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'ConfigInfo': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: SuperType
>   cannot be cast to SubType
>   .
>   .
>   .
>
> [testng] Caused by java.lang.ClassCastException: SuperType cannot be cast to SubType
>   [testng]  at SomeObj.method(SomeObj.java:22)
>   [testng]  at B.setValues(B.java:63)
>   [testng]  at ConfigInfo.init(ConfigInfo.java:64)

[testng] Caused by:

Comment: It seems you casting somewhere in SomeObject.method, could you please add code for it.

Comment: I am not explicitly casting anywhere; What I want to achieve through Spring and the use of Generics is that when A is instantiated, it is done so with an instance of B<SubType> and that Spring is able to inject an instance of SomeObj<SubType> while autowiring ObjType<SuperType>. I thought providing beans through the spring configuration will take care of this, but from what I see it's not happening and someObj.method() is getting a parameter of type SuperType.

Comment: Walk through the article, hopefully, you will get valuable information from this.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire-generics

Comment: It turned out to be too complicated to try to incorporate the above scenario in the established spring implementation (which has already been customized) so I decided to go with an approach with less abstracted components with some loss in flexibility. Thanks for the suggestions!